# Can I act as SIC with these specific type ratings?

Tags: faa-regulations, boeing-737, far-91, dc-9-family, md-80

Can I act as SIC on a part 91 ferry flight, if I hold...

- a DC-9 type rating and the flight is in an MD-80?
- a B-737 type rating, can I act as SIC on a B-737NG?

Comment: Part 91 ferry flights

Comment: Welcome to aviation..SE! If you're new to the site, the [tour] might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The single B-737 type rating includes all variants of it, from the -100 through the Max; if you were typed in a -200, you have **the** type, so there is nothing else required *in that regard* to be Second In Command (SIC) on a 737 NG. (Source... my experience, having flown the -200, classics, NG's, and the Max, all with the one "B-737" type on my certificate.)

The DC-9 family is similar; I don't think there is a separate type for the MD-80.

That all said, there are other requirements pertaining to recency of experience and training. The other answer by @wbeard52 covered these. The pilot would also need a current medical. But as far as required ratings, those mentioned in the original question are sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PIC type rating on any aircraft requiring a type rating allows the pilot to act as both PIC and SIC... in most cases.

Depending on your Part 121/135 companies training program, there may be a requirement for specific SIC flight training just like there might be a specific requirement for left and right seat flight training.

Under Part 91, there is no specific requirement to have specific flight training for either duty or pilot seat.

To act as an SIC, FAR §61.55 comes into play:

> **§61.55   Second-in-command qualifications.**
>
> > (a) A person may serve as a second-in-command of an aircraft type certificated for more than one required pilot flight crewmember or in operations requiring a second-in-command pilot flight crewmember only if that person holds:
> >
> > > (1) At least a private pilot certificate with the appropriate category and class rating; and
> > >
> > > (2) An instrument rating or privilege that applies to the aircraft being flown if the flight is under IFR; and
> > >
> > > (3) At least a pilot type rating for the aircraft being flown unless the flight will be conducted as domestic flight operations within the United States airspace.
> >
> > (b) Except as provided in paragraph (e) of this section, no person may serve as a second-in-command of an aircraft type certificated for more than one required pilot flight crewmember or in operations requiring a second-in-command unless that person has within the previous 12 calendar months:
> >
> > > (1) Become familiar with the following information for the specific type aircraft for which second-in-command privileges are requested—
> > >
> > > > (i) Operational procedures applicable to the powerplant, equipment, and systems.
> > > >
> > > > (ii) Performance specifications and limitations.
> > > >
> > > > (iii) Normal, abnormal, and emergency operating procedures.
> > > >
> > > > (iv) Flight manual.
> > > >
> > > > (v) Placards and markings.
> > >
> > > (2) Except as provided in paragraph (g) of this section, performed and logged pilot time in the type of aircraft or in a flight simulator that represents the type of aircraft for which second-in-command privileges are requested, which includes—
> > >
> > > > (i) Three takeoffs and three landings to a full stop as the sole manipulator of the flight controls;
> > > >
> > > > (ii) Engine-out procedures and maneuvering with an engine out while executing the duties of pilot in command; and
> > > >
> > > > (iii) Crew resource management training.